# Pyplot projection doesn't admit data: numpy.float64 error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am using a Mac with HighSierra, python 2.7 and Ipython 5.5.0

When using any type of projection (such as aitoff, polar, hammer, or so) in pyplot, I can't show or save the figure except if it is empty. Even if I only try to add the grid, I already have problems (of course, also with the data).

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.2))
plt.subplot( projection="aitoff")
plt.title("Aitoff projection")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Will return:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1032         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1033         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1034             func(*args)
   1035 
   1036         renderer.close_group('figure')

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2084 
   2085         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2086             a.draw(renderer)
   2087 
   2088         renderer.close_group('axes')

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1094 
   1095         for tick in ticks_to_draw:
-> 1096             tick.draw(renderer)
   1097 
   1098         # scale up the axis label box to also find the neighbors, not

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    232         if midPoint:
    233             if self.gridOn:
--> 234                 self.gridline.draw(renderer)
    235             if self.tick1On:
    236                 self.tick1line.draw(renderer)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     54         before(artist, renderer)
---> 55         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         after(artist, renderer)
     57 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/lines.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    548         funcname = self._lineStyles.get(self._linestyle, '_draw_nothing')
    549         if funcname != '_draw_nothing':
--> 550             tpath, affine = transf_path.get_transformed_path_and_affine()
    551             if len(tpath.vertices):
    552                 self._lineFunc = getattr(self, funcname)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in get_transformed_path_and_affine(self)
   2560         the path necessary to complete the transformation.
   2561         """
-> 2562         self._revalidate()
   2563         return self._transformed_path, self.get_affine()
   2564 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in _revalidate(self)
   2537             or self._transformed_path is None):
   2538             self._transformed_path = \
-> 2539                 self._transform.transform_path_non_affine(self._path)
   2540             self._transformed_points = \
   2541                 Path(self._transform.transform_non_affine(self._path.vertices),

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in transform_path_non_affine(self, path)
   2228         else:
   2229             return self._b.transform_path_non_affine(
-> 2230                                     self._a.transform_path(path))
   2231     transform_path_non_affine.__doc__ = Transform.transform_path_non_affine.__doc__
   2232 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in transform_path_non_affine(self, path)
   2225             return path
   2226         elif not self._a.is_affine and self._b.is_affine:
-> 2227             return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
   2228         else:
   2229             return self._b.transform_path_non_affine(

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in transform_path_non_affine(self, path)
   2225             return path
   2226         elif not self._a.is_affine and self._b.is_affine:
-> 2227             return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
   2228         else:
   2229             return self._b.transform_path_non_affine(

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/projections/geo.pyc in transform_path_non_affine(self, path)
    288         def transform_path_non_affine(self, path):
    289             vertices = path.vertices
--> 290             ipath = path.interpolated(self._resolution)
    291             return Path(self.transform(ipath.vertices), ipath.codes)
    292         transform_path_non_affine.__doc__ = Transform.transform_path_non_affine.__doc__

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/path.pyc in interpolated(self, steps)
    551             return self
    552 
--> 553         vertices = simple_linear_interpolation(self.vertices, steps)
    554         codes = self.codes
    555         if codes is not None:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/cbook.pyc in simple_linear_interpolation(a, steps)
   1709     new_shape = list(a.shape)
   1710     new_shape[0] = new_length
-> 1711     result = np.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype)
   1712 
   1713     result[0] = a[0]

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I have tried updating everything and also downgrading as suggested in some other posts for this numpy error in the end, and nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out: solution is to install numpy 1.11.0, but since I had several installations in my computer, it wouldn't work. I had to delete the other versions (if installed via pip this can be done manually, just erase the files), or change environment in order to use the numpy version I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/geo_demo.html) from the matplotlib page, it seems to be a good idea to stick to the function signature of [`subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)

```
subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)
#
subplot(3_digit_number, **kwargs)
```

Here you probably want a single subplot, hence

```
plt.subplot(111,projection="aitoff")
```

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I'm using Matplotlib 2.1.2

Comment: I somehow doubt that. In matplotlib 2.1.2 the function raising the error is located around line 1500 in the code, while you show it around line 1700.

Comment: It's what I get when I type help(matplotlib). Anyway, I figured it out, I had 2 installations of numpy, and it was using the 1.14 somewhere else in the computer. It works now that I am changing the environment to use numpy 1.11.0 (maybe that's what's going on with the matplotlib). Thanks for your help!